# Proving that a descending chain of subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space stabilizes

Tags: proof-explanation, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand a specific step in a proof of the statement:

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimension vector space, and $\phi: V \to V$ a linear operator such that $\phi^m = 0$ for some $m > 0$. Prove that $\phi^n = 0$.

The proof, most of which I understand, takes the following form. For each $i$, we can show that
$$
V \subset \text{Im}(\phi) \subset \text{Im}(\phi^2) \subset \ldots 
$$
The dimension of a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is less than or equal to the dimension of the ambient space, so this chain implies that
$$
\dim V \leq \dim \text{Im}(\phi) \leq \dim \text{Im}(\phi^2) \leq \ldots 
$$
If, at any step, we passed to a proper subspace, we drop a dimension, because a subspace $U$ of $V$ with the same dimension is equal to $V$. Because $V$ has finite dimension $n$, the chain can strictly decreasing for at most $n$ steps until it becomes. $0$.

The last bit of the argument which I'm not able to understand is (paraphrased):

> If there exist $i$ such that $\text{Im}(\phi^i) = \text{Im}(\phi^{i+1})$, then $\text{Im}\phi^j) = \text{Im}{\phi^i}$ for all $j \geq 1$ because the map $\phi_{|\text{Im}(\phi^i)}$ is an isomorphism.

I think it is saying that the map $\phi$ restricted to $\text{Im}(\phi^i)$, is isomorphic to its image, which is $\text{Im}(\phi^{i+1})$. Since the spaces are equal by assumption, it seems the isomorphism would just be the identity map. It certainly means they have the same dimension, but I can't figure out why the chain would need to be exactly the same space thereafter.

With this detail filled in, I think the remainder of the proof is clear. The chain would have to stay constant at some point if it didn't decrease at every step (in which case it would be $0$ in $n$ steps), and $\phi^m = 0$, so it can't stabilize at anything other than $0$.

Comment: $V\subset\mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

With the domain being the space $W := \text{Im}(\phi^i)$, the assumption in that quote is that $\{\phi(x)\}_{x \in W} = W$. And so the set $\{\phi(\phi(x))\}_{x \in W} = \{\phi(x)\}_{x \in W} = W$ and so on forevermore.